# Populate dropzone.js with image from the database issue removing images

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have an issue trying to remove the files which I have passed dropzone.js after calling the database.

When I navigate to the page and upload a new image and then remove it without refreshing the page it all works as expected.

Below is my current upload method

```
 myDropzone.on("success", function (file, response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    file.serverId = response;
                });
```

This is what is inside the response after doing console.log(response);

```
 Object { UniqueId="evgopvdjfs1w9sos3jt5"}
```

Which is correct.

Now when I press F5 and refresh the page I populate dropzone with the following snippet which returns me the image that I've just uploaded.

```
$.getJSON("/Person/GetPreviews/").done(function (data) {
        if (data.Data != '') {

            $.each(data.Data, function (index, item) {

                var UniqueId = item.ImageName;

                var mockFile = {
                    name: item.ImageName,
                    serverId: UniqueId // This is what I need to delete the image
                };

                console.log(mockFile);

                // Call the default addedfile event handler
                myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);

                // And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
                myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, item.ImageUrl);

                myDropzone.files.push(mockFile);
             });
          }
  });
```

Now when I do console.log(mockFile); the below is shown, again this is correct.

```
 Object { name="evgopvdjfs1w9sos3jt5", UniqueId="evgopvdjfs1w9sos3jt5"}
```

Now when it comes to removing the file this is my current delete function

```
 removedfile: function (file) {
                console.log(file);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUploadedFile", "Person", new {userId= @Model.UserId})',
                    data: "id=" + file.serverId['UniqueId'],
                    dataType: 'html',
                });
                var ref;
                return (ref = file.previewElement) != null ? ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
            },
```

Now when I press remove file on the pre populated image from the database, it throws an error on

```
data: "id=" + file.serverId['UniqueId'],
```

saying its underfined, I personally cannot see how because both console.logs show the UniqueId it makes me wonder if I'm missing something when I'm pre populating dropzone with the images?

As you can see I have a console.log(file); in the delete function which when hit shows the following

```
 Object { name="evgopvdjfs1w9sos3jt5", UniqueId="evgopvdjfs1w9sos3jt5"}
```

Can anyone see whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So this question is a bit old. I came across it and also found this answer, which helped me:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/24445724/add-existing-image-files-in-dropzone

This particular question was answered here and just points out a mix-up between serverId and UniqueId:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/844